# PropTypes for Next.js: TypeError: prop_types__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...).shape is not a function

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-proptypes

I have a component in Next.js:

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export default function DetailComponent({ data }) {
    return (
        <div>
            {data.heading} {data.title}
        </div>
    );
}

DetailComponent.propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.shape({
        heading: PropTypes.string,
        title: PropTypes.string,
    }),
};
```

Which gives this error when I try to view a page with the component:

```
error - TypeError: prop_types__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...).shape is not a function
    at Object../components/section/DetailComponent.js (D:\Documents\app\frontend\.next\server\pages\section\[...slug].js:237:59)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\Documents\app\frontend\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
    at Object../pages/section/[...slug].js (D:\Documents\app\frontend\.next\server\pages\section\[...slug].js:2323:91)
    at __webpack_require__ (D:\Documents\app\frontend\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
    at __webpack_exec__ (D:\Documents\app\frontend\.next\server\pages\section\[...slug].js:2663:39)
    at D:\Documents\app\frontend\.next\server\pages\section\[...slug].js:2664:28
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Documents\app\frontend\.next\server\pages\section\[...slug].js:2667:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1102:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1131:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:967:32) {
  page: '/section/80539-asd/2'
}
```

The following works fine:

```
DetailComponent.propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.object,
};
```

Why can't I use PropTypes.shape()?

Here's my package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.22.0",
    "next": "11.1.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.42.1",
    "swr": "^1.0.1",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "11.1.2",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.26.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2"
  }
```

**Edit:**
The following seems to work... but then when are you supposed to use PropTypes.shape()?

```
DetailComponent.propTypes = {
    data: {
        heading: PropTypes.string,
        title: PropTypes.string,
    },
};
```

Comment: which version of next are you using ?

Comment: @scr2em: 11.1.2. Will update my post with my package.json...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"prop-types" was installed under devDependencies. Installing as a dependency fixed the error. `npm i prop-types -P`